# Simple Alertify Alert message only flashes on screen

Tags: javascript, alert, alertify

I'm trying to replace the standard system alert with something prettier, and thought I would give Alertify a try.   The behavior is not as expected, the alert box appears on screen for only a second before disappearing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Function:

```
        function confirmation() {
            alertify.alert("here is a message")
        }
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" CssClass="formButton" Text="Submit" OnClientClick ="confirmation();"/>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is alertify instantiated? The [documentation](https://alertifyjs.com/guide.html) mentions that by default, there is a dismiss time of 5 seconds (`notifier.delay` setting)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're loading all the required files as shown on [AlertifyJS Getting Started section](https://alertifyjs.com/guide.html) and further instructions on the [alert()](https://alertifyjs.com/alert.html) docs.
Here's a working example:

```js
// on page load
alertify.alert('On page load');

// inside function
function showPrettyAlert() {
  alertify.alert('From function');
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- alertify -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.min.css"/>

<button onclick="showPrettyAlert();">Show pretty alert</button>
```

[AlertifyJS](https://alertifyjs.com/) is awesome, I've used it in many projects. Make sure you check out the [confirm()](https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html), [prompt()](https://alertifyjs.com/prompt.html) and [notify()](https://alertifyjs.com/notifier.html) methods too.